# How to do super w show open apps of all workspaces?

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Super+W show open windows from all workspaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179951/how-do-i-make-superw-show-open-windows-from-all-workspaces)

> Note: [**a PPA is now available with a workaround**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179951/how-do-i-make-superw-show-open-windows-from-all-workspaces/179952#179952) until the bug is officially fixed in Ubuntu 12.04.2 (January 2013).

I am using Precise Pangolin and now, the comand key super w show only the apps from the current workspace. I like the old way, where i see the aplications of all workspaces. I'ts just me or its default now? How to make the old way

Comment: Bug report already filed regarding this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776