# Super + w shows windows from current workspace only

Tags: unity, windows, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do super w show open apps of all workspaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126571/how-to-do-super-w-show-open-apps-of-all-workspaces)

After upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 pressing Super + w shows the windows from the current workspace only and not from all workspaces.

How can I make unity to show again all windows from all workspaces when pressing Super + w?

Comment: You meant SUPER key instead of CTRL key, right?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126571/how-to-do-super-w-show-open-apps-of-all-workspaces

Comment: OMG sure Ctrl -> Super. And thanks for the rediŕection, didn't find it in my search.