# How do I make Super+W show open windows from all workspaces?

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

I know there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776) in 12.04 which makes the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut only show open applications/programs from the current workspace, not *all* workspaces like it should.

Is there a workaround until this bug is fixed?

> *Note:* This is *not* off-topic or a duplicate of [this closed question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126571/how-to-do-super-w-show-open-apps-of-all-workspaces) because a workaround now exists.

Comment: Note to mods and others: This is not off-topic or a duplicate of [this closed question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126571/how-to-do-super-w-show-open-apps-of-all-workspaces) because a workaround now exists.

Comment: I was and am of the opinion that even if there is a known workaround for a bug, it would still be closed as off topic. See [Marco Ceppi's answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-bugs/1318#1318). While I personally don't particularly think it is a great idea to close a question if there is a workaround, I think we should be following a given convention, whether that might be changing the scope of the site or sticking to what's the norm at the moment.

Comment: Agreed - whilst there is a workaround - this answer will effectively become irrelevant once 12.04.2 hits and as such should/will be deleted.  Close this question at the appropriate time the bug fix is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A patched `compiz-core` which fixes this bug is available from PPA

- As mentioned, this is a [Compiz bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776) which will not be officially fixed until 12.04.2 (expected January 2013.)
- **But** one of the `compiz-core` developers has made a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebsantos/+archive/ppa) with a fixed version of Compiz that solves this bug.

  - If you are unfamiliar with PPAs, you may want to read [*What are PPAs...*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and [*Are PPAs safe...*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

**To install from the PPA**:

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Add the PPA with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bsantos/ppa`
- Run `sudo apt-get update`
- Update Compiz with `sudo apt-get install compiz`

> *Note:* Installing this workaround will not break any future updates to `compiz`; between now and the release of 12.04.2, any official *compiz* updates may make the old (faulty) *Super+W* behavior return for a few days until the developer fixes it and releases the updated version to his PPA.

**Demonstration:**

*Terminal*, *Software Center*, *Firefox* and *Nautilus* are open in *separate* workspaces:

[image]

After installing the fixed PPA version, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shows all four:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many years later, in the time of writing this, it is necessary to press Super+Shift+W.