# How to make Expo list windows from all workspaces?

Tags: compiz, workspaces

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> expo only shows the windows of the current workspace. I remember 12.04 had a similar problem (it was a Compiz bug) and there was a PPA to solve that (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179951/how-do-i-make-superw-show-open-windows-from-all-workspaces) question). The problem is that PPA does not seem to be  maintained any more for Quantal 12.10 at least.

I really don't know if this is related to that bug or is just some configuration problem...

So how can I change this behaviour and get expo to show windows from all workspaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a configuration issue. You need to install Compizconfig-settings-manager from the Software Center, and then, when you run it, go to the scale plugin.

From here, you have to set the option "Initiate Window Picker For All Windows" to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. This will complain of a conflict, but all you have to do is disable "Initiate Window Picker".

You can begin using it immediately.

[image: CSSM]

Comment: This is a bug and not a configuration issue. Activating "Initiate Window Picker For All Windows" is not working in 12.04. See Bug #933776: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776

Comment: The user is on 12.10. It is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 5):

As of 14.04, you could expo windows from all workspaces using

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>