# 12.04.3 and super+w for all workspaces

Tags: compiz, workspaces

**Problem:**
I cannot get one feature working.

How do I make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> show open windows from all workspaces?

**Background:**
I installed ubuntu 12.04.3 64-bit freshly today and performed all updates.
I appears to be the same problem as detailed in this post:
[How do I make Super+W show open windows from all workspaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179951/how-do-i-make-superw-show-open-windows-from-all-workspaces)

Though my circumstances are different.

The post regards 12.04.1, and the post says that the `compiz` fix would be incorporated in 12.04.2.
I installed 12.04.3 this morning.
My compiz version is 0.9.7.12

**What I've Tried:**

1. I have tried using `compiz-config-settings-manager` (ccsm) and can verify that the keyboard short cut for super+w is correctly assigned to `Windows from All Workspaces`
2. I attempted the workaround described at the linked post.

   - A. Add the PPA with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bsantos/ppa`.
   - B. Run `sudo apt-get update` .
   - C. Update Compiz with `sudo apt-get install compiz` .
     In part 'C' `apt-get` returns that `compiz` is fully up-to-date. and does not make any changes to the system.

I can verify these results on two of my systems:
- Dell D620 (Ubuntu 32-bit)
- System76 Lemur 4 (Ubuntu 64-bit)

I'd really love to get this feature working and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Try looking in Seyboard Settings > Shortcuts, or [`ccsm`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

Comment: Hi wilf.  Thanks for the reply.  I did try ccsm initially, and I can verify that the keyboard short cut for super+w is correctly assigned to 'Windows from All Workspaces'.  I referred ccsm as compiz-config in my original post.  I will edit my original post to correct the name.

Comment: Upon your suggestion, I also checked in Keyboard Settings Shortcuts, and there is no reference to this feature.  I am not surprised by this, since this is a compiz feature.

Also, there are no other keyboard shortcuts assigned to super+w to cause conflict.